# Voltage Regulator Overall Efficiency

Tags: voltage-regulator, power-electronics, efficiency

I am working on the [ISL91302BIIZ-TR5931](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/isl91302b-datasheet) programmable voltage regulator. It is configured as a two phase output as shown in the figure below:

[image]
From the datasheet: I found that the efficiency would be 87% for VDD (0.65V) and 92% for AVDD (0.94V).
My calculation shows that the input current for VDD is *I1 = 1.184 A* and for AVDD is *I2 = 0.66 A*.

My question is: is the overall input current the sum of both currents above? How could I calculate the overall efficiency?

Thanks

Comment: Overall efficiency is still overall power out divided by power in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I guess you need to consider both the input current and efficiency of each phase. In a multi-phase voltage regulator, the phases share the load current and contribute to the overall output current, so you can't simply add the input currents together as you would for independent regulators.

To calculate the overall input current, you should consider the current sharing between the phases. The input current for each phase should be weighted by the phase's contribution to the output current. Typically, this is done by considering the phase current balance. If the two phases share the load current equally, each phase would contribute half of the output current.

In your case, you've calculated I1 = 1.184 A for VDD and I2 = 0.66 A for AVDD. If the load is evenly balanced between the two phases, you can assume that each phase contributes half of the total output current. You can calculate the overall input current by this formula,

I_in (Total) = (I1 + I2)

Now, to calculate your overall efficiency, you'll need to know the total input power and the total output power.

P_in (Total) = Vin * I_in --- Use this to find total input power

And then find the overall efficiency = (P_out / P_in) * 100%